# Question about April

Tags: pandemic-legacy-season-1

> Does a Faded Figure also count as a cube for the purpose of removing a cube?

For example the Funded Event card Remote Treatment, which allows removal of 2 cubes from anywhere on the board,

> can this be used to remove Faded Figures?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  Only things that specifically refer to Faded affect them.  Things that interact with cubes generically cannot.

This along with many other questions is handled by the [Pandemic Legacy FAQ on BoardGameGeek](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1470601/compiled-faq-spoilers-hidden-each-month-hidden-sep)